# How can I call another method outside of its class?

Tags: c#

Here is a portion of my code before I go into detail:

```
public frmAdditionTutor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Random rand = new Random();
    int NumberOne = rand.Next(500) + 100;
    int NumberTwo = rand.Next(500) + 100;
    lblEquation.Text = NumberOne.ToString() + " + " + NumberTwo.ToString() + "= ?";
    int Total = NumberOne + NumberTwo;
}

private void btnSolve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int UsersInput;
    UsersInput = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);

    if (     == UsersInput)
    {
    }
}
```

What I want to do is take the `int Total = NumberOne + NumberTwo;` and have it used down where the empty portion of the If statement is. That way it can read if those two numbers match what the user inputted. If I copied all that code in Initialize it will change the numbers THEN check, and trying to make a public method does not work. Is there any way I can call down that `Total` and bring it into the Button's `if`-statement?

Comment: Make `total` a field.

Comment: @stuartd May you provide an example?

Comment: [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your `Total` a global **field** or **property**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int Total; //or "public int Total { get; set; }"
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int NumberOne = rand.Next(500) + 100;
        int NumberTwo = rand.Next(500) + 100;
        lblEquation.Text = NumberOne.ToString() + " + " + NumberTwo.ToString() + "= ?";
        Total = NumberOne + NumberTwo;
    }

    private void btnSolve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int UsersInput;
        UsersInput = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);


        if ( Total == UsersInput)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Try Again");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same result.. When debugging, "Total" does not show up as an int.

Comment: did you put the `int Total;` line on correct place? this worked on my PC by the way. the line should be inside form class and outside any method

Comment: @BlakeBratu Or did you forget to remove `int` from the last line in the constructor?

Comment: It is in the correct position, right above public form.

Comment: @merkithuseyin Thank you so much! I was stuck on wondering what to do forever. I am beginner in programming, I referenced my books, and everything but to no avail I could not find. So as a lesson, if I describe an int in the form, I do not need to redescribe Int in the certain classes?

Comment: yes. when you declare a variable / reference type, it is available on block that was declared in **AND** in it's all sub-blocks (recursively. which means also in its sub-sub-block, sub-sub-sub-block and so on).